# show table data dynamically in textbox in react

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a problem .. I have two table and when click on table row I need to pass data in child component . (I need to show all those data in textbox) , but few field is common in both table like table1 has a field "Accountname" and table2 also has "Accountname" . so I need to show those values dynamically ,how to do that ?

Comment: Have you any code that we can see, because so called 'create my idea' code is off topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: when asking a question, you should at least provide what you have tried, what is currently happening and what is expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1x2i.png)

Hi , Hei man thanks for asking , i have given an image . here you can see both table has name column but the source is different so the name property of textbox is conflicting .